# Angular 2: Can focusin and focusout be in one event?

Tags: angular, events, hide, show

Can `focusin` and `focusout` be in one event? What is it called, then?
If not, is there a way to merge this in one function?

```js
hide(e:any) {
  $('.suggestion').hide();
}
show(e:any) {
  $('.suggestion').show();
}
```

```html
<section class="search-bar-wrapper" (focusout)="hide($event)" (focusin)="show($event)">
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First thing is you need to add `tabindex` attribute to `section` to make it to get focus event. Otherwise, it won't get focus event.

Focus event get triggered when an element is focus-able. Every time you click the element it is always get focused and we can remove the focus only on click outside the element. So, we can't remove focus on `click` event of the same element.

`focus` and `focusout` both are different events we can't merge them

You can use `*ngIf` also

```html
<section 
    class="search-bar-wrapper" 
    tabindex="-1" 
    (focus)="show($event)" 
    (focusout)="hide($event)"
>

<div class="suggestion" *ngIf="canSee">
    This is a suggestion
</div>
```

in the class of the component

```ts
casSee: boolean = false;

show(e: any) {
   this.canSee = true;
}

hide(e: any) {
   this.canSee = false;
}
```

Comment: i think that is another functionality right. You can ask a question rather than continuing this

Comment: Thanks! It Works

Answer (score 6):

You can use `(focus)` and `(focusout)` in Angular 2/4.